# iOS - Objective-C - UIScrollView Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

So I've been trying to add a UIScrollView to my iOS application but I'm having a bit of trouble with it.  It doesn't seem to scroll when I put it in the simulator.

Here's what my View Controller looks like:

[image]

I even unchecked Autolayout and am sure that I have the two labels in the UIScrollView.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: your view controller size should not be your scroll view size

Comment: @Mr.T What do you mean exactly?  Can you give me an example?

Comment: as i can see from the screenshot, your view controller is in freeform style. Dont make your view controller too big.

Comment: lets say your view controller hieght is 200, and your scroll view height is also 200, but the contentview on the scroll view height should be greater than 200 (atleast 300+) , then only scroll view will scroll

Comment: @Mr.T Thanks, I got it working.

Comment: @Mr.T How am I supposed to see the contents I put in my UIScrollView.

Comment: just put the contents on a uiview and put uiview on scroll view. Uiview can be of any height